# AngularJS and Twitter Bootstrap themes (or alternative?)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

We're looking to build an app with a bootstrap theme (e.g. https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/smartadmin-responsive-webapp-WB0573SK0) so that we can get UI that looks nice without investing too much in design.

The problem is that we want to build it around AngularJS, and from what we read about bootstrap they don't play together so well. There are workarounds e.g. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/, but we're not sure if they work well with themes. Any experience with that?

Are there any frameworks similar to Bootstrap with rich themes to choose from (or buy) that play well with AngularJS?

Comment: check out this bootstrap / angular theme builder: http://pikock.github.io/bootstrap-magic/app/index.html#!/editor

Comment: have you looked into [angular-strap](https://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/)?

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried Flatify? It's built with Angular JS and Bootstrap 3.

https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/flatify-responsive-admin-web-app-WB0977873

Answer (score 6):

Disclaimer: I own [StartAngular.com](http://StartAngular.com)

I created this website to promote Open Source Bootstrap based AngularJS themes and templates. It can serve as a good starting point for your Admin dashboard based projects.

I am continuously enhancing it with best practices like ui-router and Yeoman.

Answer (score 3):

On alternative to Bootstrap is Zurb Foundation.

http://foundation.zurb.com/

Admin themes such as this are available for it:

http://www.themplio.com/themes/pertho-admin-premium-template

As I understand it, it should work AngularJS though you will still have jQuery as a dependency.

With regard to the AngularJS Bootstrap, I really can't see why this wouldn't work with the theme, since it seems like this is just a rewrite of the javascript the functionality

Comment: Sure angular and JQuery can co-exist. But far better practice not to rely on any JQuery for good Angular development. The UI-Bootstrap project for Angular increasingly re-engineers bootstrap functionality in pure Angular. But no one seems to be developing themes with them yet.

Comment: Whoever down voted this is a bit of a weirdo. It perfectly answers the question. Asked if there were any alternatives frontend frameworks to Bootstrap which play nice with Angular js. At the time I wasn't aware of any port so it was a bit of work to get it working but it would work perfectly and is a solution. Now you can use this http://madmimi.github.io/angular-foundation/ ... though the answer below seems like a great solution

Comment: Agreed. I dont like the approach philosophically but it looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at boom admin.

http://bootstrapbay.com/preview/boom-admin-dashboard-web-app-template-B86EFAA

Seems like the most angular oriented theme around as of today (September first 2014).

uses bootstrap + LESS + other stuff obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap and angular play very well together. I am using SmartAdmin with AngularJS 1.3 and I can tell you that:

1) SmartAdmin now also provides an AngularJS version
2) Angular UI provides support for bootstrap (you have already found the framework as it seems) BUT, the thing is that angular can very well cooperate together, because they are tied to solving specific needs.

You can mix angular and bootstrap with just about anything, and still get a perfect result. The only thing I would advise you before starting with this, is to understand fully what angular does. And to use something like https://github.com/meanjs/mean beforehand in order to understand how all components fit together.